# Replacing GotoIfTime in Asterisk Lua

Tags: sql, lua, timezone, asterisk

I'm working on a database driven dialplan project in Lua with Asterisk. I have stumbled badly on replacing the GotoIfTime() application in the .conf dialplan format. As listed in [Asterisk Lua Reference](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dialplan+to+Lua+Reference) the Goto Asterisk staple really shouldn't be used in Lua which makes a lot of sense to me.

My method of checking the time conditions will be exactly the same as the GotoIfTime application as it will qualify a day of the week, time by hours and minutes, and then by account timezone. This system will have many accounts that reside in different timezones. The account's hours of operation will be determined by what time it is in the account's defined timezone.

My database structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hours` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`day_start` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`day_end` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`hour_start` int(3) NOT NULL,
`minute_start` int(3) NOT NULL,
`hour_end` int(3) NOT NULL,
`minute_end` int(3) NOT NULL,
`closed_dest_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`closed_dest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`timezone` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
);
```

And here is some very simplified usage of this operation in Lua:

```
if (open == true) then
    dial(dest_type, dest_id)
else
    dial(closed_dest_type, closed_dest_id)
end
```

Here are my points of trouble:

1. Days of the week are specified by range. How to I validate what day of the week it is when the days range are stored in a string format?
2. This system will use multiple servers with possible different timezones set on the OS. Validating the account's timezone was easy with GotoIfTime because the only thing I needed to do was point the result of the account's timezone database entry to the timezone argument of the GotoIfTime application.

Comment: 1) Why did you make everything a `varchar` instead of using more sensible data types?  2) You've not made it clear at all what you are trying to do with time zones.  Typically, time zone needs to be taken into account during the query, not after the fact.  3) Please take a step back and read this from a stranger's perspective.  I have no idea what data you are putting into any of these columns, nor can I tell how you have loaded that data into your variables, or much else for that matter.  You need to be much more concise.  Thanks.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @MattJohnson 1) Has been corrected. 2) I've added a few lines to attempt to explain what's being done with the timezones in a more clear and concise format. 3) When I wrote this question, I made the assumption that the reader would be familiar with asterisk and would understand the functionality of the GotoIfTime application as it is a staple in Asterisk. The GotoIftime application is being replaced by writing it in the Lua diaplan format for Asterisk. Frankly, I don't have a method of loading this data into Lua variables because I haven't gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around and looking through Asterisk source code, I discovered Asterisk has the ExecIfTime application built into it. Instead of writing my own time condition library in lua, I used that function built into Asterisk to accomplish what I needed to do. It was a much simpler approach.

```
local zone_dir = "/usr/share/zoneinfo/"

if (resHour.id[1] ~= nil) then
    for i=1,#resHour.id do

        local a = resHour.hour_start[i] .. ":"
        a = a .. resHour.minute_start[i] .. "-"
        a = a .. resHour.hour_end[i] .. ":"
        a = a .. resHour.minute_end[i] .. ","
        a = a .. resHour.day_start[i] .. "-"
        a = a .. resHour.day_end[i] .. ",*,*,"
        a = a .. zone_dir .. resAccount.timezone

        app.execiftime(a .. "?Set(open=1)")
     end

     if (channel.open:get() ~= "1") then
         closed()
     end
end
```

The Asterisk debug looked like this:

> Executing [blah@from-external:1] execiftime("SIP/102-00000211",
>   "9:0-19:0,mon-fri,*,*,/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago?Set(open=1)"

Answer (score 1):

If you choosed lua, you have parse date by lua itself and after that compare day of week.

Or you can use default GotoIftime, but it will jump out of this lua function, so you need write other.

In general you SHOULD NOT use LUA, unless you are familar with that language. If you are not lua expert, use dialplan or fastAGI with language you are familar with(Perl,php etc)

For more info about date parse in lua you can check this link http://lua-users.org/wiki/DateAndTime

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, but by your logic, if you're not familiar with a language you shouldn't attempt to learn it. I don't feel this is a good answer.

Comment: Sure yo uhave right point here, but if your goal is lua learn, you need go lua doc/forum site. That way will be much faster and more quality. I am sorry, unfortanly i can't say how do this task in LUA, i just can say you can't use something from asterisk realm to help do it in LUA. I am sorry, i used to work with  perl/php/c++. If you know any single language better then LUA- use that language. If you feel you not know any - learn asterisk dialplan or AEL. Using interpreter like lua inside asterisk is not best option availible, realy.